# Laptop wakes from hibernation by itself

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the cause of resuming from hibernation in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/215558/how-do-i-determine-the-cause-of-resuming-from-hibernation-in-windows-7)

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium x64. First I was having a problem with the machine waking from sleep mode by itself. I went through all the steps to disable everything that could cause it to do that, but it still wakes itself. The "Last wake" list says that my mouse was the last device to wake the machine, however the mouse has an USB transmitter that I remove as soon as it sleeps and my touchpad is disabled. Because I couldn't get it to stay asleep, I've started putting it in hibernation mode (usually by pressing the Fn+F12 keys which Sony says is for hibernation).

However, the last couple of nights the laptop has awakened from hibernation (I'm pretty sure that it's really in hibernation as the power button goes dark instead of flasing amber as when in sleep mode) all by itself (I didn't even think it was possible for it to do that!). I have checked everything that has been suggested to keep the machine from waking itself from sleep mode and everything is disabled. Powercfg shows no devices armed to wake the machine and the "lastwake" list is empty(?). It's like magic. Since this is a brand new machine, less than a month in use, I would think that a faulty power button would not be an issue, but even if it were, there is absolutely nothing that could bump the machine to jiggle the button in order for it to make contact. Also, when I wake the machine from hibernation I have to press the power button firmly in order for it to make contact. Further, were it a faulty power button, one would think that it would occasionally turn itself on from being shut down completely, but it has never done that.

I contacted Sony Vaio Support and as has been my experience with support from HP, Dell, Acer, etc., etc., they seem to know less about the machine's operation than I do. And as usual, their fix (their fix for everything) is to restore the machine to factory specs, which means I loose days worth of installing and configuring programs and then reconfiguring the machine itself. As a very last resort I have done this and there is still no change.

Just to be sure everyone understands, my laptop is waking from *hibenation* not *sleep*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the cause of resuming from hibernation in Win7?](http://superuser.com/questions/215558/how-do-i-determine-the-cause-of-resuming-from-hibernation-in-win7) and/or [Laptop starts up by itself after being in Hibernate](http://superuser.com/questions/15780/laptop-starts-up-by-itself-after-being-in-hibernate)

Comment: Notebook support's request to reinstall isn't their 'fix' for everything;  It's demanded as the first test by the manufacturers to ensure that the notebook is showing the problem in factory condition before considering it for warranty service. It sucks, but it's the way it goes with big OEMs.

Comment: techie007   First, this is _NOT_ a duplication of _ANYTHING_, as I've read all the pertinent entries and they don't answer MY question. Your comment about restoring to factory condition might be true, I just wish support techs knew that so they could STOP suggesting it after the second or third time it fails to help! Still, that does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: So you _did_ try a reinstall?  Nothing is externally plugged into the notebook (besides your mouse receiver)? It notebook isn't getting moved during it's hibernation? Agreed, your problems with support have nothing to do with your problem or the solution.

Comment: You don't say whether you've eliminated Wake on LAN as a possible culprit. If it's enabled, it'll wake your laptop not only from hibernation but even from a straight power-off. (Does your laptop ever wake from powered-off state as opposed to hibernated?)

Comment: The "Wake on LAN" is disabled. The machine has never awakened from the "power off" state. Powercfg devicequery wake_armed shows only the mouse, which is physically disconnected. No program is set to update or maintain automatically. Windows Update is set to download, but not install (I don't think that wakes the machine). Powercfg devicequery wake_programmable lists "HID non-user data filter," the mouse and "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller," but none have "allow this device to wake the computer" enabled. I'll try disconnecting the AC power and see if that works when in hibernation.

Comment: Apparently, Windows Update does wake the computer from hibernation to download updates as long as the machine is connected to AC power, as it just woke and Windows Update was downloading. Powercfg Lastwake shows wake history count as 1, but wake source as 0, that pretty much looks like Windows Update is the culprit.