# powercfg /devicedisablewake gives invalid parameters error

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I've trying to solve a problem like the one described in [Laptop starts up by itself after being in Hibernate](https://superuser.com/questions/15780/laptop-starts-up-by-itself-after-being-in-hibernate) but unfortunately the common suggestion of using powercfg to disable the LAN adapter from being able to wake the machine isn't working.  I get the following description of devices that can wake the machine:

```
C:\Users\User>powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
NVIDIA nForce 10/100 Mbps Ethernet
```

but when I attempt to disable the device I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /devicedisablewake "NVIDIA nForce 10/100 Mbps Ethernet"
Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help
```

Any ideas how I can disable this setting?

*EDIT*

It occurs to me that the problem may be the presence of a slash in the device name.  Is there some way of quoting this that might alleviate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble probably does have to do with the slash in the device name, but I'm unsure how you'd go about quoting it; the Windows command shell's quoting capabilities are both weak and bizarre. Instead of using `powercfg`, try disabling wake on the device via Device Manager:

- Start -> Run -> `devmgmt.msc`, OK
- Right-click the network adapter entry; choose 'Properties'
- In the 'Power Management' tab, uncheck 'Allow this device to wake the computer'
- If Wake-on-LAN capability is desired, check 'Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer'